# React Native Change State With Unexpected Logging

Tags: javascript, state, react-native

For context, I am working on this [React Native Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99473/introducing-react-native-building-apps-javascript)

The way this logs confuses me. The following is the console output when I changed an empty input field by typing "a" then "b".

[image: PropertyFinder]

[image: Console log]

Here's my SearchPage class. Why does `console.log('searchString = ' + this.state.searchString);` show the previous value for `this.state.searchString`?

```
class SearchPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        searchString: 'london'
    };
}

onSearchTextChanged(event) {
    console.log('onSearchTextChanged');
    console.log('searchString = ' + this.state.searchString +
     '; input text = ' + event.nativeEvent.text );
    this.setState({ searchString: event.nativeEvent.text });
    console.log('Changed State');
    console.log('searchString = ' + this.state.searchString);
}

render () {
    console.log('SearchPage.render');
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style = { styles.description }>
                Search for houses to Buy!
                </Text>
            <Text style = {styles.description}>
                Search by place name or search near your location.
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.flowRight}>
                <TextInput
                    style = {styles.searchInput}
                    value={this.state.searchString}
                    onChange={this.onSearchTextChanged.bind(this)}
                    placeholder='Search via name or postcode'/>
                <TouchableHighlight style ={styles.button}
                underlayColor = '#99d9f4'>
                    <Text style ={styles.buttonText}>Go</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
            underlayColor= '#99d9f4'>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Location</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Image source={require('image!house')} style={styles.image}/>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` can be an asynchronous operation, not synchronous. This means that updates to state could be batched together and not done immediately in order to get a performance boost. If you *really* need to do something after state has been truly updated, there's a callback parameter:

```
this.setState({ searchString: event.nativeEvent.text }, function(newState) {
    console.log('Changed State');
    console.log('searchString = ' + this.state.searchString);
}.bind(this));
```

You can read more on `setState` in the documentation.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: Thanks Colin. This definitely helps. I'm coming to React Native development from a background of mainly Objective-C. So the world of javascript and React is fairly new. Would you recommend any websites for learning javascript / react beyond the documentation?

Comment: My main recommendation would be to learn the basics of JavaScript and then lay React on top of it. To that end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript